# Probability density, bivariate

Tags: probability-distributions, multiple-integral

Hi i have a problem where i am really unsure if my solution is correct.
I tried using Mathjax but it did not work out.....that is why i am including a picture of my solution.

The problem:

$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{4} (x+y)$ if $0<x<y<c$, else 0

calculate c

[image]

Comment: $\left[xy+\frac{y^2}{2}\right]\big|^{y=c}_{y=x}=cx+\frac{c^2}{2}-\frac{3x^2}{2}$. And the correct answer is $c=2$.

Comment: @Song many thanks, how could I oversee that!